# Fastest way to get variable substring lengths from file (C#)

Tags: c#, datatable, substring, streamreader

I have a text file that has values that need to be extracted and each value is a variable length. The length of each variable is stored in a `List<int>`, this can change if there is a more efficient way.

**The Problem:** What is the fastest way to get the variable length substrings into a `DataTable` given a `List<int>` of lengths?

Example text file contents:

```
Field1ValueField2ValueIsLongerField3Field4IsExtremelyLongField5IsProbablyTheLongestFieldOfThemAll
A1201605172B160349150816431572C16584D31601346427946121346E674306102966595346438476174959205395664
```

Example `List<int>`:

```
11, 19, 6, 21, 40
```

Example output `DataTable`:

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Field1Value | Field2ValueIsLonger | Field3 | Field4IsExtremelyLong | Field5IsProbablyTheLongestFieldOfThemAll |
| A1201605172 | B160349150816431572 | C16584 | D31601346427946121346 | E674306102966595346438476174959205395664 |

There is no pattern to the field values, could be any alphanumeric value, and can only get the field values via the length list.

My approach was as follows:

```
List<int> lengths = new() { 11, 19, 6, 21, 40};

DataTable dataTable = new();

//Add Columns for each field
foreach (int i in lengths)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add();
}

//Read file and get fields
using (StreamReader streamReader = new(fileName))
{
    string line; //temp
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Create new row each time we see a new line in the text file
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

        //Temp counter for starting index of substring
        int tempCounter = 0;

        //Enumerate through variable lengths
        foreach (int i in lengths)
        {
            //Set the value for tat cell
            dataRow[lengths.IndexOf(i)] = line.Substring(tempCounter, i);

            //Add the length of the current field
            tempCounter += i;
        }

        //Add Row to DataTable
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient (time and/or memory) way of completing this task?

Comment: On what basis have you concluded that you have a performance problem?

Comment: Side note: consider sticking with commonly used patterns when posting code like ` foreach (int i in lengths)` - it is extremely unusual to use `i` for anything but *index* in an array...

Comment: *dataRow[lengths.IndexOf(i)]* surely this will fail if two lengths are the same? Anyhoo, you don't foreach and then derive index from value with indexof.. you derive value from index with a normal for and use `lengths[i]`

Comment: @KirkWoll I was running some test where I hard coded the variable lengths into the .Substring() method and then I tested using this process of storing the variable lengths and found the hardcoded version faster by a, some what, slim margin, but when you start to take in files that are 100's of thousands of lines long, there's a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you producing that input string or that length array?

If yes:

- save index of every Nth field starting character (if you already have length-array, then you can build a start-array too)
- then when decoding, use multiple threads to parse multiple index points at once and join them on a target list or array (imo an array must be faster since you have total number of fields)

If no:

- push every encountered field start into a queue(with their field index) and jump directly to next field
- asynchronously pop elements from queue by other threads and place them into the list accordingly with their index (array could be better if total length known)

because when you do both extracting and parsing in same loop, the extracting throughput drops. So you should offload the work to other threads, maybe with N fields at once to tolerate multi-threading synchronization latency.

If extracting by single-thread is too slow compared to multi-thread parsing, then you can try to vectorize the extracting. Launch 128 char samplers at once, check if they find a prefix code and do a reduction between them to find the first prefix in them (if they find multiple).

Comment: Multithreading didn't even cross my mind somehow. Using a starting index, in conjunction with the length, is actually a lot easier than I thought and is obviously faster than what I was doing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Computing starting points could be parallelized too. It was called parallel prefix sum scanning.